# Trainable variables in loss function

Tags: tensorflow, model, loss

I try to understand how to add trainable variable in my model.
I wrote some code :

```
def custom_loss( y_true, y_pred, k1, k2, k3):
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred))
  cosine0 = cosine_dist(y_true[:MAX_BITS],y_pred[:MAX_BITS])
  error = custom___error(y_true,y_pred)
  loss = loss * k1 + cosine0 * k2 + k3 * error
return loss

model.compile(loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, k1, k2, k3), optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[‘accuracy’,custom_error,custom___error])
```

But the variables k1, k2, k3 never change : how can I add them to the trainable variables list ?

```
k1: <tf.Variable ‘Variable:0’ shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=0.5>
k2: <tf.Variable ‘Variable:0’ shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=0.5>
k3: <tf.Variable ‘Variable:0’ shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=0.5>
```

Regards

Comment: This setup doesn't really make sense anyway as the model can just set all k to 0 to "minimize" the loss.

Comment: You're right . It's only to show what I want to do : If only they could become null. But they don't change.